# Limiting coupon uses per customer

Tags: coupon-codes, magento2.4.3

I have currently got the 'Uses Per Customer' set to 1 on a specific coupon. However, it can be used in multiple orders by the same customer, despite them being logged in. I am using Magento 2.4.3. Has anyone else encountered this before and know how to fix it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

Marketing -> Cart Price Rule -> Select specific rule -> Select specific coupon code and then set value in Uses per coupon & Uses per Customer.

Uses per Coupon: Set the number of times the Coupon can be used.
Uses per Customer: Set the number of times the same client uses the Coupon.

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0):

**1** - Have rabbitmq installed and with its account;

**2** - Execute the Magento CLI command from Magento root directory: **bin/magento setup:config:set --amqp-host=127.0.0.1 --amqp-port=5672 --amqp-user=guest --amqp-password=guest --amqp-virtualhost=/** (Note- Here u have to change the parameter values according to your account);

**3** - Run this command too before placing next order - **bin/magento queue:consumers:start sales.rule.update.coupon.usage &**

Answer (score 0):

**Affected products and versions**

Adobe Commerce (all deployment methods) 2.4.3 and above

**Issue**

Merchants set up a coupon for single use and customers are able to use it multiple times.

**Cause**

Merchants do not have sales.rule.update.coupon.usage consumer set up and running that results in improper behavior.

**Solution**

Add the sales.rule.update.coupon.usage consumer to the app/etc/env.php file.

```
...
    'cron_consumers_runner' =>
    array [
        'cron_run' => true,
        'max_messages' => 20000,
        'consumers' =>
        array [
            'sales.rule.update.coupon.usage'
        ]
    ],
...
```

Run this command - `bin/magento queue:consumers:start sales.rule.update.coupon.usage &`