# magento2.4.3-p1 coupon set to Uses per Customer = 1 is applied more than once for a customer

Tags: coupon-codes, magento2.4.3.p1

Sames as :
[Limiting coupon uses per customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/350998/limiting-coupon-uses-per-customer)
But solution does not work. That feature worked as desired on Magento 2.4.2.

Comment: Looks like a native bug on 2.4.3.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed. It is a native bug.

Comment: do you have a link to further information about this bug i.e. a github issue?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35077#

Answer (score 1):

**Affected products and versions**

Adobe Commerce (all deployment methods) 2.4.3 and above

**Issue**

Merchants set up a coupon for single use and customers are able to use it multiple times.

**Cause**

Merchants do not have sales.rule.update.coupon.usage consumer set up and running that results in improper behavior.

**Solution**

Add the sales.rule.update.coupon.usage consumer to the app/etc/env.php file.

```
...
    'cron_consumers_runner' =>
    array [
        'cron_run' => true,
        'max_messages' => 20000,
        'consumers' =>
        array [
            'sales.rule.update.coupon.usage'
        ]
    ],
...
```

Run this command - `bin/magento queue:consumers:start sales.rule.update.coupon.usage &`

Comment: I am facing this issue in 2.4.5-p1 also. where uses per coupon and per customer both are set to 1. 
Even after using coupon for once, again most of the time again applying coupon is success.( Sometimes it worked and throws error). Using full page cache.

Querty: is this a exiting issue in 2.4.5-p1 also and does the above sol with work.

Comment: and what is that command for. what this command will do. Is it for 1 time or every time we need to run. Do we also need to run this cmnd in prod for once.

and magento doc https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/miscellaneous/coupon-code-used-more-than-once-adobe-commerce.html?lang=en not mentioned of this cmd any reason.

Comment: Does this command related with below cron and if yes than what time interval in general we need to set here and what time intervale we need to set if client is testing in every 30 sec to 1 min with same coupon. and how it is different for https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/miscellaneous/coupon-code-used-more-than-once-adobe-commerce.html?lang=en
Cron configuration options for group:consumers
Generate Schedules Every
Schedule Ahead for
Missed if Not Run Within
Use Separate Process

Comment: Running it one time is enough.

Comment: Have you added sales.rule.update.coupon.usage consumer to the app/etc/env.php file?

Comment: Thank you for your clear solution. It looks like you cannot do without RabbitMq for this, even on 2.4.6 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/38017